# Escape Javascript String

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

As part of a div overlay, I have written some code to make a button. This function accepts an Object

```
    function f1(marker){
    var notesBox = '<div id="saveMarkerNotesDiv'+marker.id+'"> <input type="button" onclick="saveMarkerNotes(\''+ marker+'\')" id="saveMarkerNotes'+marker.id+'" value="Save" /> </div>';
return notesBox;
    }

function saveMarkerNotes(marker){
 alert(marker);
//Just shows [object Object]
alert(marker.id);
//Above line throws an error as it cannot find id in the **string marker**. 
}
```

Question is why is turning into a string when I have escaped it. Also i used the same object in the previous method f1 and there it works fine.
When the above f1 function is called, it has the object marker. I can access the attributes and properties of marker in the method.

The above function f1 has the marker object. However when the function saveMarkerNotes() is called, it does not seem to have the object anymore. When I print marker.id in saveMarkerNotes() it shows undefined and when I show the marker object in the alert it shows up as [object Object]. I feel that the marker object is turning into a string and does not remain an object anymore in the onclick="saveMarkerNotes(\''+ marker+'\')" code. How can I escape the string so that it remains an object and not a string.

Comment: Strings are just text.  It makes no sense to have an object inside of a string.  You may be looking for JSON.

Comment: The function you posted doesn't really do anything.

Comment: *"I feel that the marker object is turning into a string"* – That is correct, since you're concatenating a string there. It doesn't matter that that string represents HTML markup, it's still just a string, and that can't transport objects. The sane way would be to not work with HTML markup, but with DOM elements. E.g. `document.createElement('input').onclick = saveMarkerNotes.bind(null, marker)`…

Comment: @Pointy, i have updated the code

Comment: @deceze, well i know its turning into a string. You can very well pass objects if you wish in javascript. I have already done that in the f1 function. It seems to me that I have not been able to get the correct escape sequence in the next method.

Comment: You can indeed pass objects in JavaScript, but you're creating JavaScript code as text for an HTML attribute. HTML does not understand or care about JavaScript; all that object can be in that context is text (a string).

Comment: You would need to turn the object into a text representation of itself, which can be transported in a string. That is called *serialisation*, and JSON would probably be the appropriate format there. However, JSON cannot transport *everything* of a Javascript object, you'll lose all instance methods for example if it has any. Again, the sane way is not to go from Javascript through a string back to Javascript, but to work with the DOM API and programmatically create elements to which you can attach pure Javascript functions/objects/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DOM API to generate DOM elements (`<div>`s etc.) and attach event handlers to them programmatically using Javascript. Don't go through concatenating strings which will be interpreted as HTML which attaches elements to the DOM which eventually triggers Javascript again from strings.

```
let input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
input.id = 'saveMarkerNotes' + marker.id;
input.value = 'Save';
input.addEventListener('click', saveMarkerNotesDiv.bind(null, marker));

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'saveMarkerNotesDiv' + marker.id;
div.appendChild(input);

return div;
```

You now need to `.appendChild(div)` to some element to add it to your page. Yes, this may seem more verbose and annoying, but it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation and sample code. I understand how that works and have done some tweaks now to generate the elements like you have mentioned.